# Adding AR(1) term to multiple regressions in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lapply, lm, autoregressive-models

I am running 503 separate regressions, each with a separate dependent variables, with 3 independent variables and 1 AR(1) term.

**Data:**

```
# fake data 
set.seed(333)
df <- data.frame(seq(as.Date("2017/1/1"), as.Date("2017/2/19"), "days"),
                 matrix(runif(50*506), nrow = 50, ncol = 506))

names(df) <- c("Date", paste0("var", 1:503), c("mktrf", "smb", "hml"))
```

I create the AR(1) process as follows, using a function called lagpad:

```
lagpad <- function(x, k=1) {
  i<-is.vector(x)
  if(is.vector(x)) x<-matrix(x) else x<-matrix(x,nrow(x))
  if(k>0) {
    x <- rbind(matrix(rep(NA, k*ncol(x)),ncol=ncol(x)), matrix(x[1:(nrow(x)-k),], ncol=ncol(x)))
  }
  else {
    x <- rbind(matrix(x[(-k+1):(nrow(x)),], ncol=ncol(x)),matrix(rep(NA, -k*ncol(x)),ncol=ncol(x)))
  }
  if(i) x[1:length(x)] else x
}
```

Then I store my necessary variables for regression:

1. **All the dep var**

   ```
   x = df[,505:507]
   ```
2. **All the indep var**

   ```
   y <- df[,2:504]
   ```
3. **AR(1) process**

   ```
   y_lag <- lagpad(y, -1)
   ```
4. **Fit all the models**

   ```
   list_models_AR= lapply(y, function(y) 
          with(x, lm(y ~ mktrf +  smb + hml + y_lag, na.action = na.exclude)))
   ```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use `lapply` in this case, since there are multiple components of *y_lag* that need to be called, one for each regression.

Comment: Perhaps something like: `lapply(1:503, function(n) {ly <- y[[n]];  lpy=lagpad[[n]]; lm( y ~ .+lpy, data=x)})`. This looks like a mess to analyze sensibly. Multiple comparisons is a statistical quagmire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of your lag term, it seems to be actually the next y-column. If so you can create 502 models as follows:

```
list_models_AR= lapply(1:(ncol(y)-1), function(i) lm(y[,i]~x[,1] +  x[,2] + x[,3] +y[,i+1], na.action=na.exclude))
```

Comment: Why would I use y[,i+1] instead of y_lag[,i]? Can you explain what that y[,I+1] is doing?

Comment: Reproducing your code I get `y_lag ` to be a list of 550 elements together with a warning. Each element of the list is equal to one step further element of your `df`, e.g. `y_lag `== df[,2]. So instead I put inside the loop `lapply` the equivalent expression. The 502 models in the final list are `y[,1]~x[,1] +  x[,2] + x[,3] +y[,2] ... y[,502]~x[,1] +  x[,2] + x[,3] +y[,503]`